# PHP Get data from tables that do not have a specific relationship

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I have two tables (CONTROL & PAYMENT) that looks like this:

```
          CONTROL                                       PAYMENT
+--------------------------+                   +------------------------+
|  CNUMBER    |    SERIAL  |                   |  NUMBER    |   STATUS  |
+--------------------------+                   +------------------------+
| C-200-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    200     |    PAID   |
| C-201-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    201     |    PAID   |
| C-202-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    202     | PROCESSING|
| C-203-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    203     |    PAID   |
| C-204-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    204     | PROCESSING|
| C-204-1     |  SUDU-03   |                   |    205     | PROCESSING|
+--------------------------+                   +------------------------+
```

I want to show a list like this:

```
+--------------------------+
|  CNUMBER    |    STATUS  |
+--------------------------+
| C-200-1     |    PAID    |
| C-201-1     |    PAID    |
| C-202-1     | PROCESSING |
| C-203-1     |    PAID    |
| C-204-1     | PROCESSING |
| C-205-1     | PROCESSING |
+--------------------------+
```

So, I need get data (SELECT) from table "control" using "serial" (in control table) like a search criteria to find the "status" (in payment table) through "number" (in payment table) using %LIKE% (to match "number" and "cnumber")

I am trying but still I can't figure it out!
I hope someone can help me and give me any idea.

EDIT:

SOLUTION 1:

---

select c.CNUMBER,p.STATUS from CONTROL c
inner join PAYMENT p on substr(c.CNUMBER,3,3)=p.NUMBER;

---

Thanks to @Syscall I solved the main problem but I just have a little issue:

How I can show all the values even payment entries are null/empty ?
If the entry on 'control' exist but in 'payment' not

something like that:

```
+--------------------------+
|  CNUMBER    |    STATUS  |
+--------------------------+
| C-200-1     |    PAID    |
| C-201-1     |            | <--empty
| C-202-1     | PROCESSING |
| C-203-1     |    PAID    |
| C-204-1     |            | <--empty
| C-205-1     | PROCESSING |
+--------------------------+
```

EDIT 2:

SOLVED, USING LEFT JOIN
Thanks again @Syscall.

SOLUTION:

---

select c.CNUMBER,p.STATUS from CONTROL c
left join PAYMENT p on substr(c.CNUMBER,3,3)=p.NUMBER WHERE col1 = '$var'

---

Comment: `C-205-1` seems to not be present in your table `CONTROL`. Is it intentionnal?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. Yes it was intentional, because im showing 6 entries from each table. So cnumber(control) and number(payment) can be repeated sometimes too.

Comment: Did you try `left join` instead of `inner join` ?

Comment: Yes! It worked perfect!Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `INNER JOIN` using `SUBSTR` :

```
select c.CNUMBER,p.STATUS from CONTROL c
inner join PAYMENT p on substr(c.CNUMBER,3,3)=p.NUMBER;
```

Outputs :

```
+---------+------------+
| CNUMBER | STATUS     |
+---------+------------+
| C-200-1 | PAID       |
| C-201-1 | PAID       |
| C-202-1 | PROCESSING |
| C-203-1 | PAID       |
| C-204-1 | PROCESSING |
| C-204-1 | PROCESSING |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: While this is the best answer for the *stated* situation, it should be noted that performing a join on not just an unindexed column, but a *computed value* will perform terribly. You should strongly consider adding something like a `payment_id` column in the `CONTROL` table.

Comment: @Sammitch Yes, I know what are you talking about! Would be more easy with something matching both tables, like a 'id'. But that tables wasn't created to work together from the beginning, so i'm trying to fix it.

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' What is your error ? You could try something like `select c.CNUMBER,p.STATUS from CONTROL c inner join PAYMENT p on substr(c.CNUMBER,3,3)=p.NUMBER where c.dcon = "something"`.

Comment: @Syscall Great that works now! I added a WHERE clause to this SELECT and works too, but just shows me entries which exist on both tables. How I can perform it to show all entries ? because sometimes control has a new entry but the ‘payment’ entry still doesn’t exists. For ex, the entry C-425-1 can exist in 'control' but the payment hasn't be made, so, how I can show something like this 
| CNUMBER = C-425-1 | STATUS = empty/null |

Im using this:
select c.CNUMBER,p.STATUS from CONTROL c
inner join PAYMENT p on substr(c.CNUMBER,3,3)=p.NUMBER WHERE dcon = ‘something’

Comment: @IrvıngNgr' In this case, change `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT JOIN`. Inner join will get records that match, left join will get records and let empty (null) records that doesn't match. Not sure I'm clear :)